# Angular 2 Auth guard breaks redirect

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

This is my `app-routing.module.ts`:

```ts
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/app/elements', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {path: 'app', component:ElementsComponent, children:[
    { path: 'details/:id', component: ElementDetailComponent, canActivate:[AuthGuard]},
    { path: 'elements',     component: ElementListComponent, canActivate:[AuthGuard] },

    { path: 'user/signup',     component: SignupComponent },
    { path: 'user/login',     component: LoginComponent },
    { path: 'user/logout',     component: LogoutComponent }
  ]}

];
@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ],
  providers: [AuthGuard]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

As you can see for the path `''` I am redirecting to `/app/elements` which is kind of my home page. This was working fine until I implemented the `AuthGuard` which looks like:

```ts
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate{

  public allowed: boolean;

  constructor(private af: AngularFire, private router: Router) { }


  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    this.af.auth.subscribe((auth) =>  {
      if(auth == null) {
        this.router.navigate(['/app/user/login']);
        this.allowed = false;
      } else {
        this.allowed = true;
      }
    });
    return this.allowed;
  }
}
```

Now, if the user is not logged in and goes to `http://localhost:4200/`, the redirect works and it tries to go to `http://localhost:4200/app/elements`, the guard detects the user is not logged in and it redirects to the login page.

The problem is if the user *is* logged in and tries to go to `http://localhost:4200/`. In this case, nothing happens, the user stays at that URL with the page blank.

Why the redirect is not working in that case? Is there a way to fix that?

Answer (score 4):

the `canActivate` returns before the `firebase` observable resolves, so `canActivate` will always return false, but `canActivate` can return a promise or an Observable.

that should work :

```
canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.af.auth
                  .map(auth => auth != null)      // null means not authenticated
                  .do(isAuthenticated => {   // change routes if not authenticated
                     if(!isAuthenticated) {
                       this.router.navigate(['/app/user/login']);
                     }
                  });

}
```

Comment: @Snorkpete, why did you edit the answers? The original works, although the edited doesn't. If you want to propose a different approach, why just don't create a new answer?

Comment: I agree with you, but @snorkpete`s  answer is kinda professional

Comment: My apologies. I was considering proposing a different answer, but to me, the real answer to the question is that you were not handling the asynchronous nature of the firebase authentication service properly. The example code is just to highlight that core fact - i didn't think it was worth a whole separate answer.

Comment: I'm not seeing why the current code doesn't work though. Is it typescript compilation error from not importing the do and map operators?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a service that keeps the the state of the authentication. After that just use a code without subscription. Because it's executed async and brakes the code.

```ts
public canActivate() {      
    if (this.authService.isAuthenticated) 
      return true;
    this.router.navigate(['/app/user/login']);
    return false;
}
```